# Spring Framework : which template engine?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, tiles, thymeleaf

I plan to dive into Spring Framework. I'm seduced by the huge documentation, the annotations system and the flexibility provided by this software.
But, before going further, I would like to have some opinions on which template engine to use.

The documentation list those template systems :

- JSP/JSTL
- Thymeleaf
- Tiles
- Freemaker
- Velocity

Of course, I have an idea about the well know JSP, what about the others ?
You can answer in the basis of these concerns :

- readability
- flexibility
- ease of use
- ease of learn
- lasting quality
- Conjunction with a client library (AngularJS)
- ...

Thanks in advance !

PS : sorry for my English level...

Comment: As you said spring has wide documentation . why dont you find something  ?

Answer (score 2):

Well, your question is a little border line here, because SO tries to avoid opinion only answers. So I'll try to document the particularities of the framework you have cited. But I must admit that what I find good of bad is only my opinion ...

JSP/JSTL is the base and even if you plan using other framework you must know this one. Main qualities : extensively documented, and can be single stepped in debuggers (nice for beginners ...). Main drawbacks : too easy to put java code in view, and control statement are verbose.

Tiles : is does not by itself generate views but combines other (generally JSP) partial views to form a full page, typically page header, footer, menu, etc. Is more a complement to JSP/JSTL than an alternative

Velocity/Framework : true templating systems. That means that it is not converted to a java servlet like a JSP, but they contain placeholders and are merged at runtime. In fact, both allows control statements like contitionnals (`if`), loops (`foreach`), and direct acces to request, response, session and servlet context. Main qualities : said to be fast, Velocity offers a `VelocitiyLayoutView` which is not so far from Tiles. Main drawbacks : said to use lot of memory, sometimes things that woold look simple are not allowed (they are templating systems and not source interpreters after all) and Spring Velocity integration is rather outdated.

Thymeleaf : TO BE DOCUMENTED (do not know it, but if someone wants to edit my post, please do it)

Answer (score 0):

I use JSP/JSTL because it is a standard. In addition to that, I also use spring forms and tangs in addition. Your IDE can suggest tags and attributes because it is XML based on your JSP.

When you are coding on your JSP page, you are on the presentation layer of your application. So, you don't need too advanced functions (provide a model or process data in your service object).